# LibGDX: How do I manage Player position?

Tags: java, libgdx, isometric, coordinates

I'm making a 2D isometric tiled game using LibGDX. In my Player class, I created a vector2 that I named 'pos' to manage the player position, then I draw my Player with:

```
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(localPlayer.texture,LocalPlayer.pos.x,LocalPlayer.pos.y);
    batch.end();
```

Let's say pos = (0,0), then the Player will be rendered at the bottom left corner of my screen.

When I translate the camera, the (0,0) still correspond with the bottom left of my screen, so the pos Vector2 is about my screen, not my map...

What should I do to get a Coordinate System based on the map and not on my screen? I would not prefer using the Sprite Class...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at model view protection matrix (matrix transformations):
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

This is related to OpenGL, but the operations are similar in any library.

Comment: Basically model Is the position I  the map...view is the position on the screen...projection is either ortho or persp

Comment: This is good, however with LibGDX you can do it automaticly by calling     >batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)

Comment: Yeah..it depends in the framework. But the concept was same. Btw I am an openGL guy